# vim: Moving cursor to beginning/end of insertion

Tags: vim

While in insert mode, is it possible to move to the beginning/end of the insertion?

Just to clarify I'm **NOT** asking how to move to the start of the line, paragraph, or word.

Since vim disables backspace beyond insertion, depending on backspace mode, it must know where the insertion begins and ends, right?

Comment: If you describe what your use case, there may be better options than needing to know those locations.

Comment: Free your backspace by adding `set backspace=indent,eol,start` to your `~/.vimrc` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
<ctrl-o>`[
```

`<ctrl-o>` allows you to perform one normal mode command before going back into insert mode.

---

After the comments below I realise you will need to set a mark as you enter insert mode

```
nnoremap i mii
```

or

```
autocmd! InsertEnter * :normal mi
```

(Although the autocmd won't work properly when entering insert mode not using `i`)

You can then go back to where you entered insert mode using

```
<crtl-o>`i
```

Comment: Will the `[` mark be set while you're still in insert mode?

Comment: The output from `<ctrl-o>:marks` makes us think `<ctrl-o>'[` is promising but it doesn't do what the OP wants for some unknown reason...

Comment: @jamessan It kind of does, since it will go to the first character of the most recently yanked or *changed* text. Text changes are often due to editing in insert mode, but obviously not always.

Comment: @nodakai You need to use the backtick motion rather than apostrophe: `<c-o>\`[`. However, it doesn't really do what the OP wants because any time the cursor is moved while still in insert mode and then text edited, the mark will be set to that new location. It will not always be the position where insert mode was entered.

Comment: @KurtHutchinson You're right.  I was testing with getpos('`[') when I should have been trying getpos("'[").